# Description ENGINE LOG in IBM ILOG CPLEX

Tags: websphere, cplex

I want to understand engine log of IBM ILOG CPLEX studios for a ILP model. I have checked there documentation also but could not able to get clear idea.

Example of Engine log :

```
Version identifier: 22.1.0.0 | 2022-03-09 | 1a383f8ce
Legacy callback                                  pi
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 139 rows and 37 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 156 coefficients.
Aggregator did 11 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 286 rows, 533 columns, and 3479 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 403 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 129 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.05 sec. (6.16 ticks)
Found incumbent of value 233.000000 after 0.07 sec. (9.40 ticks)
Probing time = 0.00 sec. (1.47 ticks)
Tried aggregator 2 times.
Detecting symmetries...
Aggregator did 2 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 284 rows, 531 columns, and 3473 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 402 binaries, 129 generals, 0 SOSs, and 129 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.01 sec. (2.87 ticks)
Probing time = 0.00 sec. (1.45 ticks)
Clique table members: 69.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 0.00 sec. (0.50 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                          233.0000       18.0000            92.27%
*     0+    0                          178.0000       18.0000            89.89%
*     0+    0                           39.0000       18.0000            53.85%
      0     0       22.3333   117       39.0000       22.3333        4   42.74%
      0     0       28.6956   222       39.0000     Cuts: 171      153   26.42%
      0     0       31.1543   218       39.0000     Cuts: 123      251   20.12%
      0     0       32.1544   226       39.0000     Cuts: 104      360   17.55%
      0     0       32.6832   212       39.0000     Cuts: 102      456   16.20%
      0     0       33.1524   190       39.0000      Cuts: 65      521   14.99%
Detecting symmetries...
      0     0       33.3350   188       39.0000      Cuts: 66      566   14.53%
      0     0       33.4914   200       39.0000      Cuts: 55      614   14.12%
      0     0       33.6315   197       39.0000      Cuts: 47      673   13.77%
      0     0       33.6500   207       39.0000      Cuts: 61      787   13.72%
      0     0       33.7989   206       39.0000      Cuts: 91      882   13.34%
*     0+    0                           38.0000       33.7989            11.06%
      0     0       33.9781   209       38.0000      Cuts: 74      989   10.58%
      0     0       34.0074   209       38.0000      Cuts: 65     1043   10.51%
      0     0       34.2041   220       38.0000      Cuts: 63     1124    9.99%
      0     0       34.2594   211       38.0000      Cuts: 96     1210    9.84%
      0     0       34.3032   216       38.0000      Cuts: 86     1274    9.73%
      0     0       34.3411   211       38.0000     Cuts: 114     1353    9.63%
      0     0       34.3420   220       38.0000      Cuts: 82     1402    9.63%
      0     0       34.3709   218       38.0000      Cuts: 80     1462    9.55%
      0     0       34.4494   228       38.0000      Cuts: 87     1530    9.34%
      0     0       34.4882   229       38.0000      Cuts: 97     1616    9.24%
      0     0       34.5173   217       38.0000      Cuts: 72     1663    9.16%
      0     0       34.5545   194       38.0000      Cuts: 67     1731    9.07%
      0     0       34.5918   194       38.0000      Cuts: 76     1786    8.97%
      0     0       34.6094   199       38.0000      Cuts: 73     1840    8.92%
      0     0       34.6226   206       38.0000      Cuts: 77     1883    8.89%
      0     0       34.6421   206       38.0000      Cuts: 53     1928    8.84%
      0     0       34.6427   213       38.0000      Cuts: 84     1982    8.83%
Detecting symmetries...
      0     2       34.6427   213       38.0000       34.6478     1982    8.82%
Elapsed time = 0.44 sec. (235.86 ticks, tree = 0.02 MB, solutions = 4)

GUB cover cuts applied:  32
Cover cuts applied:  328
Implied bound cuts applied:  205
Flow cuts applied:  11
Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  17
Zero-half cuts applied:  35
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  1

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    0.43 sec. (235.61 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 8 threads:
  Real time             =    0.27 sec. (234.23 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.11 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =    0.71 sec. (469.84 ticks)
```

Mainly I want to understand what are nodes,left,gap,root node processing, parallel b&c.

I hope anyone of you will give a resource or explain it clearly so that it can be helpful when someone starts using IBM ILOG CPLEX studio in future

Thanks a lot in advance

I am expecting for someone to fill knowledge gaps regarding Engine log of IBMs ILOG CPLEX studio

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

Progress reports: interpreting the node log

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.8.0.0?topic=mip-progress-reports-interpreting-node-log

Comment: I have seen that could not able to understand.

Comment: So... do you know anything about how search algorithms like branch-and-cut work? Do you know what the nodes in the search tree are?